# Create a tree with categories with get_posts()

Tags: posts

I have my posts using this code :

```
$dataQuery = [
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'documentation',
    'meta_query'    => $meta_query,
];

$documentations = get_posts($dataQuery);
```

Where `$meta_query` is an array. It's working, I have my posts, but I want to show a tree with the categories and the posts inside ? Is it possible easily ?

For now, I will get my categories and loop over them and then get posts for each category... Since `get_posts()` doesn't return any information about the category. I guess there is a better way ?

Comment: "For now, I will get my categories and loop over them and then get posts for each category" - how about the other way round - loop through the posts and collect the categories, then filter/group them accordingly. The good side is, there'd be just one `WP_Query` call, but more processing upon displaying the posts.

Comment: Because in this way, I think I will have more queries, since I have more posts than categories

Comment: Then I guess you already are using a good approach and can keep doing it that way.. (do correct me if I misunderstood your previous comment..)

Comment: Honestly you are right, it's just weird form me that you can't do a jointure easily on the terms / caterogies from the main query. But my approach is working. I will close my ticket soon since I am looking for tuning.

Comment: `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` only returns post/`WP_Post` objects (or IDs if `fields` is set to `ids`) and not terms. There's the `tax_query` parameter for querying posts in certain taxonomies, but the returned data would still be post objects/IDs. To get the post categories, you'd need to use functions like `get_the_category()` or `get_the_terms()` for custom taxonomies.